# Is there any way to know if a button is not clicked a determined time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to know if a button is not clicked a determined time?
I've two increment and decrement buttons (plus and minus )to control the temperature with Ajax request. The value is incremented one to one with the next function:

```
Plugin_increment.prototype.startPluginTempe = function (selector, dataAux, dataAux2, varAux, varAux2) {
    var valueElement = $(selector);
    function incrementValue(e){
        if((valueElement.text() < 40) && (valueElement.text() > 10)){ //max and min
            valueElement.text(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment)); 
        }

        if(valueElement.text() == 40){//max
            if(e.data.increment == -1){
                valueElement.text(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment));
            }
        }
        if(valueElement.text() == 10){//min
            if(e.data.increment == 1){
                    valueElement.text(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment));                  
                }   
        }
        //Ajax request??????
        return false;
    }
    $(varAux).button({
              icons: {
                 primary: "ui-icon-plusthick"
              },
              text: false
        }).bind('click', {increment: 1}, incrementValue);       
    $(varAux2).button({
              icons: {
                 primary: "ui-icon-minusthick"
              },
              text: false
        }).bind('click', {increment: -1}, incrementValue);

};
```

"selector" is the selector of a span to show the value. "varAux" and "varAux2" are the selectors to plus and minus buttons.

If I send an Ajax request for each increment, the client is overloaded. I think that an option could be to know if a button is not clicked a determinated time. Another way?

I use jquery-ui to plus and minus buttons.

Comment: Why don't you disable the buttons until the ajax request has finished?

Comment: Because the increment is made one to one, if I want to increase the value on five unities. There will be five Ajax requests. There would be unnecessary requests

Answer (score 1):

You can impose a minimum interval between AJAX requests. If the button is clicked twice within that interval, only one request will be performed, like this:

```
function incrementValue(e) {
    //your existing code here
    scheduleAjaxRequest();
}

var minimumTimeBetweenAjaxRequests = 500; // in milliseconds
var ajaxRequestIsScheduled;

function scheduleAjaxRequest() {
    if (ajaxRequestIsScheduled) {  
        // two or more clicks within specified interval, 
        // the data will be sent in request that's already sceheduled
        return;
    }
    ajaxRequestIsScheduled = setTimeout(doAjaxRequest, minimumTimeBetweenAjaxRequests);
}

function doAjaxRequest() {
    //Ajax request
    ajaxRequestIsScheduled = null; // clear timeout ID to allow next request to be scheduled
}
```

Comment: One potential problem with this approach is that if AJAX request fails for some reason, client-side data and server-side data will be out of sync. So you should consider handling AJAX errors appropriately

Comment: Is a great idea, but I would prefer to realize only one request when the multiple clicks stop. The finality is to reduce the Ajax requests, not delay them. There would be unnecessary requests